# How to route to another component on onDidDIsmiss method on an IonAlert

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ionic4

When the user access the dashboard component , I want to check if the user is logged in, if he's not, the component displays an Alert that prompts to the user either to log in or cancel. when he clicks on confirm the user should be automaticly redirected/ routed to the login component.
here is my code :

```
    ... state:{isLoggedIn:false,showAlert:true}
    componentDidMount(){
         const checkLogin=this.props.location.state;
         if(checkLogin){
            this.setState({isLoggedIn:true,showAlert:false})
        }
    }
    //render part
    <IonAlert isOpen={this.state.showAlert} onDidDismiss={()=>(
         <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>  
        )} animated="true" header="connection" message="Vous devez etre connecté"
         buttons={['Login']}>
        </IonAlert>
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC. Then you will be able to this.props.history.push("/path");

Comment: thanks @Tulshi. i have changed the code on  "onDidDismiss={()=>(
        this.props.history.push("/login")
    )} and it works pretty well.